# Edge module import or export unexpected

Tags: microsoft-edge, microsoft-edge-extension

I used Microsoft Edge Extension Tookit to port a Chrome extension into Microsoft Edge.

When i load the extension in Edge, the console send me an error :

> SCRIPT1086: SCRIPT1086: Module import or export statement unexpected
>   here

It point to the first statement of the source code (background.js) who looks like :

```
import ClientManager from './services/ClientManager'
```

and ClientManager is a class in a services subdirectory :

```
class ClientManager {
    [...]
}

export default ClientManager;
```

so i don't know what is wrong with that, i'm using the last version of Edge (not insider)

Microsoft Edge 41.16299.15.0

Microsoft EdgeHTML 16.16299

EDIT: problem solved. Apparently the Edge extension converter tool didn't save the manifest file updated, i just copy and paste manifest from the tool and now it works.